# I cant increase specific value at my list in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I use python for my autonomous car project. So, I worked on an algorithm that returns values from the Dijkstra algorithm. I give the algorithm (location, destination) and it returns the shortest path. And then I'm adding the directions values. But I cant increase the values at some point. Here is my code:

```
coordinates = [['X',0,20],['B',15,20],['H',15,45],['G',20,45],['Y',20,55]]
dir = dijsktra(graph,'X','Y')
indexes = []
for i in range(len(dir)):
   for j in range(len(coordinates)):
           if dir[i] == coordinates[j][0]:
               indexes.append(j)

for i in range(len(dir)-1):
    if coordinates[indexes[i]][1] == coordinates[indexes[i+1]][1]:
        turnons.append(['R',i+1])
    elif coordinates[indexes[i]][2] == coordinates[indexes[i+1]][2]:
        turnons.append(['L',i+1])

list_lenght = len(dir) + len(turnons)
for i in range(list_lenght):
    for j in range(len(turnons)):
        if turnons[j][1] == i:
            dir.insert(i,turnons[j][0])
            if turnons[j] != turnons[len(turnons)-1]:
                print(turnons[j])
                turnons[j + 1][1] += 1 // That's is the problem.
```

This is the expected output: `['L', 1]['R', 3]['L', 5]['R', 7]`

This is what i get: `['L', 1]['R', 3]['L', 4]`

Here

- L = left
- R = right

Comment: Are you sure that you are going through the if statement that correspond to the increment ?

Comment: Please share full code with variables `coordinates`, `indexes` etc. to be able to debug it

Comment: @Alderven i update my code.

Comment: Also add `dijsktra`, `graph`and `turnons`.

Comment: @Alderven turnons is an empty list and Dijkstra basically returns the shortest path X to Y

Comment: Still doesnt work... Waiting for Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ladies and Gentlemen, We Got Him.**

```
coordinates = [['X',0,20],['B',15,20],['G',20,45],['Y',20,55],['H',15,45]]
dir = dijsktra(graph,'B','X')
indexes = []
for i in range(len(dir)):
    for j in range(len(coordinates)):
            if dir[i] == coordinates[j][0]:
                indexes.append(j)

turnons = []
newdir = []
for i in range(len(dir)-1):
    if coordinates[indexes[i]][1] == coordinates[indexes[i+1]][1]:
        turnons.append(['R',i+1])
    elif coordinates[indexes[i]][2] == coordinates[indexes[i+1]][2]:
        turnons.append(['L',i+1])

uzunluk = len(dir) + len(turnons)
turnsyc = 0
dirsyc = 0
print(dir,turnons)
for i in range(uzunluk):
    if i % 2 == 0 or i == 0:
        newdir.append(dir[dirsyc])
        dirsyc += 1
    else:
        newdir.append(turnons[turnsyc][0])
        turnsyc += 1
```